# How integrate pasm PRU compiler for BeagleBoneBlack into Yocto

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack, bitbake, texas-instruments

I want to integrate the pasm compiler (provided here https://github.com/beagleboard/am335x_pru_package) into my Yocto configuration. Previously I have built my PRU sources on the BBB target itself. But now I want to have this done during the bitbake process.

However, copying the prebuild pasm binary from the pru_sw/utils/ folder to either /usr/bin or ~/bin did not do the trick.

My recipe triggers a make which calls the pasm compiler which is not known to the bitbake process:

```
make: pasm: Command not found
```

Does any has some experience or hints??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after spending some time searching, I did not find any solutions on how to use the pasm compiler out of the box for Yocto. In the end, I just created a new recipe inside my custom layer which simply clones the PRU repo (see original post)  and triggered the already shipped `linuxbuild` script, which worked fine. Finally, I just needed to reference the built `pasm` binary from my dependent recipes  to build the PRU binaries. I am not sure if this is the supposed way, but it works for my purpose.

Any additions to this is welcome!